# How to remove Flicker in Winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to stop the flickering in Windows form c#?

```
private void btnBFS_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    infoGroupbox.Text = "Breadth First Search";
    travinfo.Hide();
    bfsinfo.Show();
}
private void btnBFS_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    infoGroupbox.Text = "Traversal";
    bfsinfo.Hide();
    travinfo.Show();
}
```

Im expecting smooth transition but when i transition to other panel or groupbox it flickers.

Comment: Without futher infos, I'd say you could try with `DoubleBuffered = true`

Comment: "Im expecting smooth transition". Then you should use a UI technology that can accomplish that. Winforms isn't really that technology to achieve that easily or in getting even reproducible behavior on different systems. DoubleBuffered often helps a bit but whatever happens on your Container Controls it has influence. Different controls on those panels will have different behavior. So we can't really give good hints without knowing.

Comment: Please avoid asking the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76295509/5114784) question again and again. Instead, edit your question to make it more clear. For example, it's not clear what animation you're talking about. In your yesterday's question it seemed that you were trying to move these buttons. Or did you assign an animated bitmap to its `Image`? Or do you render a custom animation in its `Paint` event? How do you do any of these? What "transition to other panel or groupbox" suppose to mean? More context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following code helps to remove flickering. Just setting DoubleBuffered = true is often not enough. The following code can be applied to a form or a panel in which the problematic controls are located.

```
public void EnableDoubleBuffering()
{
   // Set the value of the double-buffering style bits to true.
   this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | 
      ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
      ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,
      true);
   this.UpdateStyles();
}
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Smooth transitions in WinForms are not easy to accomblisch. You need to override the Paint of a control and work with timers.